# openedge db startup error

Tags: openedge, progress-db

```
proenv>proserve dbname -S 2098 -H hostname -B 10000

OpenEdge Release 11.6 as of Fri Oct 16 19:02:26 EDT 2015

11:00:35 BROKER     This broker will terminate when session ends. (5405)

11:00:35 BROKER     The startup of this database requires 46Mb of shared memory. Maximum segment size is 1024Mb.

11:00:35☻ BROKER  0:  dbname is a void multi-volume database. (613)

11:00:35 BROKER   : Removed shared memory with segment_id: 39714816 (16869)

11:00:35 BROKER     ** This process terminated with exit code 1. (8619)
```

I am getting the above error when I tried to start the progress database...

Comment: from a fresh install? any more info you can prove on this?

Comment: how the database is created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

11:00:35☻ BROKER 0: dbname is a void multi-volume database. (613)

My guess is, you have just created the DB using prostrct create. You need to procopy an empty db into your db so that if has the schema tables.

procopy empty yourdbname

See: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P7713

Answer (score 0):

The database is void it means, it does not have any metaschema.
First create your database using **.st** file (use **prostrct create**) than 
copy meta schema table using **emptyn**.

Ex : **procopy emptyn urdbname.**

Then try to start your database.